# Using a Jinja2 for loop with a javascript alert

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I've been trying to create a webpage where after receiving user input, it would display the history of all user input after pressing submit, however this is working as intended. However I wanted to implement an alert box which would show additional information. However as everything else is printed correctly, since the alert box uses an onclick event, it would only output the very last sample of user input.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Enrolment page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if all_users %}
        {% for user in all_users %}
            <h1> Hi, {{ user[0] }}) </h1>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Details</button>
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    alert("{{ user[1] }}, {{ user[2] }}");
                }
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
    {%else%}
        No users to show
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

In my code, all_users is the information from a csv file, however that is working fine. My only problem is the alert is not showing the information I want. Is there a way to store each set of user details in each script to print out each button since it is only displaying the last set of user details.

Comment: If I'm understanding your intent correctly, I think you have too much happening inside the Jinja2 for loop, i.e, code repeating that should not be repeating.  Rather than just looking at the functional result produced by this code, try looking at the html source that is produced and start debugging from there.

Comment: @TimD Which part do you mean should not be repeating?

Comment: If you have N rows in all_users, this code will produce html source with "Hi, user[0]" N times, produce N buttons and N script functions, etc.; I think, if I'm following along correctly.

Comment: @TimD Yep, exactly what I'm looking for. Is something wrong by doing it like that?

Comment: No problem; I misunderstood your intent.  I will add a possible approach below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `user[0]` and `user[1]` in the `myFunction()` call like:

```
{% for user in all_users %}
    <h1> Hi, {{ user[0] }}) </h1>
    <button onclick="myFunction('{{user[1]}}, {{user[2]}}')">
        Detail
    </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Then change the function to:

```
function myFunction(users) {
      alert(users);
}
```

Comment: I retested and made one final change and everything is working. I believe it is what you are looking for. Editing the original now. Place the function script outside of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

To work this in Jinja2, you might try using a string variable and appending each value as in (code not tested):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Enrolment page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if all_users %}
        {% set AllUserList = "" %}
        {% for user in all_users %}
            {% set AllUserList = AllUserList + user[1] + ", " + user[2] + "\n" %}
            <h1> Hi, {{ user[0] }}) </h1>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Details</button>
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    alert("{{ AllUserList }}");
                }
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
    {%else%}
        No users to show
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element 3. How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like it works in the code, but the button remains unresponsive.

Comment: Inspecting the html source code shows that it looks normal except for after the alert("{{ AllUserList }}");. The last bracket and semi-colon are on a new line?

Comment: By removing the new line character it just prints the last user[1] and user[2]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have buttons on top of buttons?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Where N is number of rows in all_users, do you see N buttons or just one?  This was regarding your "unresponsive" button.  Anyway, I think I will humbly bow out of this question.  I thought I had an idea for you, but something else that I'm not seeing is amiss with the logic.